# Как правильно задать права доступа для сайта в Linux?

Tags: linux, администрирование

Как правильнее разграничить доступ к файловой системе? Сайт у которого есть скрипты (апач должен их читать), конфиги (апач должен их читать и писать), файлы бд (субд должна их читать и писать) и при этом у пользователя ос должны быть права чтобы он мог заменять и файлы скриптов и конфига.

Насколько правильный следующий вариант (если не правильный, то какой вариант будет правильным?

```
/home/ (стандартные права)
    mysite/ (владелец "администратор_пк", права 700)
        db/ (владелец "администратор_субд", группа "пользователи_субд", права 770)
        conf/ (владелец "апач", группа "апач", права 770)
        site/ (владелец "апач", группа "апач", права 470)
```

Пользователь "администратор_пк" входит в группы: "пользователи_субд", "апач"

Будет ли в таком случае доступ у субд и апача к нужным им файлам?

PS: Вопрос о том как правильно разграничить доступ для файлов БД, скриптов, конфигов чтобы с этими файлами могла работать и субд и апач и пользователь (через аналог "Проводника" в Линуксе). Причем я хочу чтобы у пользователя были права на редактирование скриптов, а у апача - нет.

Comment: Не пробовали рассматривать вариант отказаться от апача? Запуск php-fpm от имени произвольного пользователя решил бы кучу проблем

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум в .htaccess в папках /db и /conf `Deny from All` апач будет иметь доступ к ним, но извне будет закрыто.

С другой стороны, непонятно, вы хотите, чтобы несколько пользователей имело доступ к mysite?

Comment: Если бы я хотел чтобы апач имел ко всему доступ, я бы не задавал вопрос о разграничении доступа на уровне Линукса. Вопрос о том как правильно разграничить доступ для файлов БД, сриптов, конфигов чтобы с этими файлами могла работать и субд и апач и пользователь (через аналог "Проводника" в Линуксе). Причем я хочу чтобы у пользователя были права на редактирование скриптов, а у апача - нет.